# WebdriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, appium

I keep getting the follow error randomly when running Appium tests:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy
>   command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I've tried to google but could not find anything that can help to solve this issue.  This error happens at random times during a test run: clicking an element, finding an element, sending keys, keyboard actions, etc. The worst part about it is that sometimes an entire suite of tests will run flawlessly with no issues.

I have the following caps:

```
params.put("appPackage", "com.chewy.android");
params.put("appActivity", "<activity>"); //Tried without adding as well
params.put("browserName", ""); //Tried without adding as well
params.put("platformName", "Android");
params.put("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
params.put("automationName", "uiautomator2");
```

appium-java-client: 5.0.0-BETA8 (I've also tried downgrading)
appium server: 1.6.4 (I've also tried downgrading and upgrading)

Here are the logs:
[image: Appium Server Logs]

I've tried to adjust the 'newCommandTimeout' command as well.  The red flag I see in the logs that something is up with UIAutomator2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: This issue was happening in 32 bit devices. I used 64 bit devices like iPhone6 and above, the issue does not exist. Also try running appium in no reset mode.

Comment: @shiv ok will try - thanks